# How to access the values from a custom object in react native

Tags: react-native, components

So I started working on a notes app using react native and i came across an issue where i pass a subcomponent a variable i made called category. In the attached image, you can see that when i call console.log(category), the category along with all of its subcategories is displayed. However, if i call category.categoryName (one of the parameters of category), it returns undefined and not the actual category name that is stored in the category variable. Any idea why this is?

```
function CategorySection(category){
console.log(category)
console.log(category.categoryName);


(On console):
DG
{"category": ("categoryColor": "#FFC626",
"categoryName": "Ideas",
"categoryNotes": [[Object], [Object]], "id":
"0.7169790275245845"}}
DG
undefined
```

I passed the ‘category’ variable to this screen through its parameters, and then passed it to this subcomponent. I was expecting to be able to access the information contained within this variable (specifically the category name). And display the name on the screen.

Comment: Your cateogry object format is weirded. Can you confirm your `categoryName` key is located in the root of object?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah i figured it out, so when i pass a ‘category’ object, and call it, it is passed as a ‘prop’ (or whatever you name the props in your receiving function). In this case, i would need to say category.category.categoryName
I ended up just naming the input as ‘props’ so it read easier when i called props.category.categoryName or whatever i needed to access from the category.